# Matlab Coin Toss Simulation

Tags: matlab, random, plot, percentage

I have to write some code in Matlab that simulates tossing a coin 150 times. I have to count how many times the coin lands on heads and create a vector that gives a running percentage of the heads.

Then I have to make a table of the number of trials, random 'flips", and the running percentages of heads. I assume random "flips" means heads or tails for that trial.

I also have to create a line graph with trials on the x-axis and probabilities (percentages) on the y-axis. I'm assuming the percentages are just the percentage of getting heads.

Sorry if this post was long. I figure giving the details now will make it easier to see what I was trying to do with the code. I didn't create the table or plot yet because I'm not even sure how to code for the actual problem.

```
NUM_TRIALS = 150;
trials = 1:NUM_TRIALS;
heads = 0;
t = rand(NUM_TRIALS,1);
percent_h = zeros(size(t));

for i = trials

    if (t(i) < 0.5)
        heads = heads + 1;
        percent_h = heads./trials; 
    end   
end

flips = t;

disp('Number of Trials, Random flips, Heads Percentage')
disp([trials', flips, percent_h'])
plot(trials,percent_h)
title('Trial Number vs. Percent Heads')
xlabel('Trial number')
ylabel('Percent Heads')
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is actually pretty close to answering your question, but there are a few issues that I see.

- You should index `t` by the current trial number.
- Likewise, `percent_h` should be indexed accordingly. This should be pre-allocated as well.
- Not sure what `z` is supposed to represent...
- To make the plot, just use `plot`. `xlabel` will give a label to the x axis, `ylabel` to the y axis. `title` will give a name to the plot.
- You should divide by `i`, not trials.

So, your code should look something like this. There's a fair number of ways to simplify it, but I'll preserve your code as much as possible.

```
NUM_TRIALS = 150;
trials = 1:NUM_TRIALS;
heads = 0;
t = rand(NUM_TRIALS,1);

percent_h=zeros(size(t));

for i = trials

    if (t(i) < 0.5)
        heads = heads + 1;
    end
    percent_h(i) = heads/i;  
end
plot(trials,percent_h)
xlabel('Trial Number')
ylabel('Percent Heads')
title ('Trial Number vs Percent Heads')
```

[image]

Comment: I guess I have to read up on indexing because I didn't know about that. I'm taking a programming class and they just threw Matlab into the last couple weeks of the semester. I'm trying to add more info here but it seems like itt won't let me. I will edit my original post.

Comment: You should divide by i, not trials

Comment: I've tried that and I'm still getting weird values. Dividing by i I get this error message "??? Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent."  I think the probability calculation is good becuase the values look to be converging to 0.5, but the graph is still hyperbolic.

Comment: I'll post my exact.  might have changed something that is throwing it off. I'll edit the OP with the newest code.

Comment: I tried changing the code around a lot. Sometimes using precent_h and sometimes using percent_h(i). With the exact code as in the OP, but with percent_h(i) this is what I see: "Number of Trials, Random flips, Heads Percentage
??? Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent."

Comment: With the code in the OP it works good. I guess the graph is supposed to be hyperbolic? I thought the graph was supposed to look like this http://www.engr.mun.ca/~ggeorge/4421/demos/t2/i26plot.jpg. My last question would be how can I convert each random value to either heads or tails and display that in the 2nd column of my table. I want <5 to be heads.

Comment: That's really a different question... I've posted what I get for output, for your comparison.

Comment: I don't know why I'm not getting the graph you are getting. Could you incorporate my code for generating a table of data and see if you still get the same graph? That seems to be the only difference in the code.

Comment: I finally got it to work. The code is a little different than yours because I had to include the code to generate a data table. That was what was causing the error. I think the only thing I have to do now is mess around with num2str type commands to get the random numbers to become either 'h' or 't'. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It says I need 15 reputation to vote up an answer. I currently only have 14 reputation  points.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually solve this more simply by taking advantage of a few other MATLAB functions, as hinted at by @PearsonArtPhoto. Firstly, you can use [RANDI](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) to generate the coin tosses as ones for a head. Then, you can use [CUMSUM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) to get the cumulative number of heads. Dividing this element wise by `1:n` gives you the cumulative fraction of heads.

```
n=150;
ishead = randi([0,1],1,n);
plot(cumsum(ishead)./(1:n));
```